# ¿como convierto esta consulta SQL en LinQ con EntityFramework?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, sql

```
**SELECT** E.*
**FROM** Enrollment.E
**JOIN** STUDENT.S **ON** S.ID = E.StudentID
**WHERE** CourseID = (num);
```

E= tabla enrollment que crea una relacion entre las tablas COURSE y STUDENT.
directamente de un DB de sqlserver.

Comment: Hola Ruiz. Tal vez quieras darle una mirada a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. A como está, es probable que sea votada negativamente y/o eliminada.

Comment: Te falta saber de donde vienen los datos, en el caso de que lo hicieras a traves del ORM. te dejo una respuesta, pero estara incompleta porque no decis de donde proviene la fuente

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes, recorrer esa consulta con un foreach o ejecutarla con un metodo.
En el primer caso te la dejo ejecutada para obtener ese `List<T>`. en el segundo ejemplo esta con el foreach.

```
var collection = (from m in db.Enrollment
                             where m.CourseID == CourseID //variable pasada desde algun lado
                             join s in db.tbl_usuarios on m.StudentID equals s.ID
                             select m).ToList();
```

**Segundo caso:**

```
var collection = from m in db.Enrollment
                             where m.CourseID == CourseID //variable pasada desde algun lado
                             join s in db.tbl_usuarios on m.StudentID equals s.ID
                             select m;

 foreach(var item in collection)
 {
     //con la variable item obtenes cada registro.
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, bro el caso del foreach me funciono.

Comment: @Ruiz tomate un rato en entender como funcionamos mirando el [tour]... la forma de decir gracias es aceptando la respuesta...